# How can we represent this Probability Distribution Function as a Cumulative Distribution Function?

Tags: probability

Suppose we roll 2 dies. X is a random variable that represents the sum of the values of both dies.

Then, $$P(3 \le X \lt 4) = \frac {1}{36} + \frac {2}{36} = \frac {3}{36} = 0.083.$$

How can we represent this probability as a Cumulative Distribution Function?

Comment: $P(3\leq X <4)=)F(4)-F(3-)$ where $F$ is cumulative distribution function and $F(3-)$ means that you do not include 3

Comment: @Don F(4) would include P(X=4) so you might be thinking about P(3<=X<4)=F(4-)-F(3-), which, for integer valued random variables such as X, is also F(3)-F(2).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the (general) cdf you can look at the table of the outcomes.

\begin{array}[ht]{|p{0.2cm}|||p{0.5cm}|p{0.5cm}|p{0.5cm}|p{0.5cm}|p{0.5cm}|p{0.5cm}|p{0.5cm}|p{0.5cm}|p{0.5cm}|}  \hline \text{Sum }   & \color{blue}1 &\color{blue}2 &\color{blue}3 &\color{blue}4 &\color{blue}5 &\color{blue}6  \\ \hline   \color{red}1 &2 &3 &4 &\color{green}5 &6 &7 \\  \hline \color{red}2 & 3 &4 &\color{green}5 &6 &7&8  \\ \hline \color{red}3&4 &\color{green}5 &6 &7 &8&9 \\ \hline \color{red}4 &\color{green}5 &6 &7&8&9&10  \\ \hline  \color{red}5 &6 &7&8&9&10&11  \\ \hline \color{red}6 &7&8&9&10&11&12  \\ \hline \end{array}

Each outcome has the same probability, which is $\frac{1}{36}$. Then count  the equal outcomes and add them up successively.  They are on the bottom left to up right diagonals, for instance the green diagonal of 5´s .

Then the cdf is

\begin{array}[ht]{|p{0.2cm}|||p{0.5cm}|p{0.5cm}|p{0.5cm}|p{0.5cm}|p{0.5cm}|p{0.5cm}|p{0.5cm}|p{0.5cm}|p{0.5cm}|p{0.5cm}|p{0.5cm}|p{0.5cm}|p{0.5cm}|p{0.5cm}|}  \hline  x    &2 &3 &4 &5 &6 &7&8&9&10&11&12 \\ \hline   F_X(x) &\frac{1}{36} &\frac{3}{36} &\frac{6}{36} &\frac{10}{36} &\frac{15}{36} & \frac{21}{36} &\frac{26}{36} &\frac{30}{36} &\frac{33}{36} & \frac{35}{36} & 1\\  \hline \end{array}

The cdf can also written as a piecewise defined function.

The number of cummulative outcomes for the sum up to 7 is

$\sum_{i=2}^x \left( i-1 \right)$

This can be simplified to $\frac{x^2-x}{2}$

And the number of cummulative outcomes for the sum up to 12 is

$\sum_{i=2}^7 \left( i-1 \right)+\sum_{i=8}^{12} \left( 13-i \right)$

It can be transformed to

$21+\frac{25x-x^2}{2}-63=\frac{25x-x^2}{2}-42$

Therefore the cdf is

$F_X(x)=\begin{cases}\frac{1}{36}\cdot \frac{x}{2} \cdot (x-1), \ \texttt{if} \ x\in \{2,3, \ldots , 7 \} \\ \frac{1}{36}\cdot \left( \frac{25x-x^2}{2}-42 \right), \texttt{if}  \ x\in \{8,9, \ldots ,12\} \end{cases}$

Answer (score -1):

We have $$P(3\le X\ <4)=P(3\le X \le 3)=P(X\le 3)-P(X\le 2)=F(3)-F(2)$$